How to fix Firebase Analytics purple error: This code path does I/O on the main thread underneath that can lead to UI responsiveness issues
Recently Xcode started showing a purple error on Firebase Analytics, please take a look:

In text:

{"message":"This code path does I/O on the main thread underneath that can lead to UI responsiveness issues. Consider ways to optimize this code path","antipattern trigger":"-[NSBundle bundleIdentifier]","message type":"suppressable","show in console":"0"}
{"message":"This code path does I/O on the main thread underneath that can lead to UI responsiveness issues. Consider ways to optimize this code path","antipattern trigger":"-[NSBundle bundlePath]","message type":"suppressable","show in console":"0"}

I use SwiftUI and have it installed via CocoaPods. I haven't changed any code recently. I've checked the docs and I can tell that Firebase didn't change the initialization process code either.
Is there anything I must do?

Potentially related to Firebase issue #12640?

You can also just turn off the “Thread Performance Checker” in your scheme diagnostic settings. In Xcode 15.3 release notes, they talk about about this adding this test to that diagnostic, so (temporarily) turning off these diagnostics might avoid the problem.
