Swift: "This code path does data processing on the main thread" warning after updating to Xcode 15.3
I have the following code in Swift:
func someFunc() {
    if let managedContext = context ?? managedContext {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Groups> = Groups.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", group.name)
        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) -----> warning appears on this line
            // Processing results
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}

It is working as expected, but after updating Xcode to 15.3, I started getting the following message:
{"message":"This code path does data processing on the main thread. Consider ways to optimize this code path","antipattern trigger":"-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]","message type":"suppressable","show in console":"0"}

I've tried to find information on how to fix this, but I haven't been successful. Any ideas on why this warning appears and what should be done to resolve it?
Thanks!

Looks like it is the "thread performance checker" setting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78368863/how-to-fix-firebase-analytics-purple-error-this-code-path-does-i-o-on-the-main

If warning about problem appeared with Xcode 15.3 doesn't mean that problem doesn't existed before. Context's fetch should be called inside perform closure.

thanks guys you gave me useful info to investigate

I tapped on the ? icon in the warning message in Xcode and simply followed Apple's instructions to switch off the Thread Performance Checker. Not sure if this is an ideal solution! (Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme, then Diagnostics tab)
